# Oracle dataguard - Redo transport

Tags: database, oracle, transactions, rdbms, dataguard

In a low bandwidth environment when a transaction commits that generates a large amount of redo data will cause other independent transactions to slow down. This is because the redo data of small transactions will be blocked until the large redo data of the previous transaction is transported to the  DR site. Is there a way that we can control small redo data takes priority over the large one so the other independent transactions complete quicker.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question would be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Copied to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77930/oracle-dataguard-redo-apply

Answer (score 0):

No.  Redo is contiguous and must be sent and applied in order.  You should also look at the MAA Best Practices for tuning the network for Data Guard at [9.3.7 Use Data Guard Transport and Network Configuration Best Practices](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10803/config_dg.htm#CEGHIEIE)